# ios Chromecast sender: [NSMutableDictionary gck_loadFromCacheWithName:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1133f1678

Tags: ios, chromecast, sender

Im trying to build a chromecast sender app for ios. I am running the HelloVideoGoogleCast successfully. Now mimicking that, I use these lines in my app:
 // Chromecast added section:
    kReceiverAppID= @"65E5F27B"; // the app code

```
// Establish filter criteria.
GCKFilterCriteria *filterCriteria = [GCKFilterCriteria
                                     criteriaForAvailableApplicationWithID:kReceiverAppID];
// Initialize device scanner.
self.deviceScanner = [[GCKDeviceScanner alloc] initWithFilterCriteria:filterCriteria];
```

and I get the following error on the last line:
[NSMutableDictionary gck_loadFromCacheWithName:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1133f1678

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSMutableDictionary gck_loadFromCacheWithName:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1133f1678'

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `-ObjC` linker flag to your Other Linker Flags entry in the Build Settings part of XCode.

Those categories should then be loaded from the static library once that's in, and you'll be good to go!

As an alternative, consider using [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/) to integrate the google-cast-sdk, which will do this for you!